# Function called by password_reset action passed only 1 argument instead of 2 in PHP 7.2.11

Tags: password

WordPress Version: 4.9.8

Note that the below happens only in PHP version 7.2.11 and in 7.0.32 it works fine!

password_reset action is suppose to call function with 2 arguments but I am getting this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function changeServerPassword(), 1 passed in
>   /home/hm/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288 and
>   exactly 2 expected in
>   /home/hm/public_html/wp-content/plugins/[path].php:9, referer:
>   https://domain.com/wp-login.php?action=rp

So for some reason, it looks like WP is calling my function with only 1 argument. Any idea why this is happening? Following is a sample code that I am using:

```
add_action('password_reset', Array(new className(), "changeServerPassword"));
```

Inside the class className:

```
// $pass is not passed by wordpress and so it results in the above error
public function changeServerPassword($user, $pass) {
    // do things here
}
```

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/315234/update-option-option-too-few-arguments/315237#315237. You need to specify the number of arguments for your hook. It isn't working fine in PHP 7.0, the password will always be null, but in PHP 7.2 this was changed to a fatal error.

Comment: @TimothyJacobs Ah! That solved the problem. I would not have found that. Thanks for pointing it out. Does it mean that all add_action call should now have the number of arguments specified every time?

Comment: If you have more than one argument, then yes. This isn't new though. If you omitted that previously, you would just be experiencing silent bugs.

Comment: @TimothyJacobs I don't have many other actions being used so other things works fine. Thank you so much.